# Date Format changes when inserting into table if start date and end date cross one or more months

Tags: date, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an Access 2013 form which has two unbound date fields, FromDate and ToDate. I insert these into a table (TblGuestBooking) which has an autonumber key field, so this doesn't feature in the SQL statement to follow.

If the FromDate and ToDate are in the same month, the dates are entered as dd/mm/yy, the format of the form field. If, however, the From date  is in one month and the to date is in the next month or later month, the format changes to mm/dd/yy for the subsequent months.

for example 26/2/14 to 3/3/14 results in the following table entries:

26/02/14,
27/02/14,
28/02/14,
03/01/14,
03/02/14,
03/03/14

This is the code snippet I am using to put the dates into the table (BookingID is obtained from the form.)

```
Dim BookingDate As Date

Dim SQLString As String

....

BookingDate = FromDate

Do
    SQLString = "INSERT INTO TblGuestBooking ([BookingDate], [BookingID])  VALUES (#" & BookingDate & "#" & "," & Me.GuestSuiteBookingID & ")"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQLString
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    BookingDate = BookingDate + 1
Loop Until BookingDate = ToDate + 1
```

If you've read this far, thank you for your time. If you can help me out, many, many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When processing date literals (text values enclosed by "hash marks" `#`) Access SQL will **always** interpret ambiguous `xx-yy-zzzz` dates as `mm-dd-yyyy`, regardless of the regional setting in place on the computer. So, if your machine is configured to display short dates as `dd-mm-yyyy` and you create an Access query that uses `#04-02-2014#` it will *always* be interpreted as April 2, not February 4.

The solution is to always format date literals as unambiguous `yyyy-mm-dd` values. In your case, instead of

```
... VALUES (#" & BookingDate & "#" ...
```

you would use something like

```
... VALUES (#" & Format(BookingDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#" ...
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that s try.  I am aware that the SQ Date format is midday and have a function elsewhere to manage the difference when building an sql string.  What the me was that the conversion did not take place for some dates, but did for others. If I were to apply the function it would merely swap the wrongs to right and rights to wrong.  Thank you for your reply

Comment: Apologies for the gobbledygook. Responded on smartphone which isn't too smart when it comes to predictive text!

Comment: Yep. It worked. Don't know why, but don't have the time to care. Imposing a format seems to have cured the erratic behaviour and that's all I need at this point in time. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've used following code for an ASP page that create and update a Date field in Access database.

```
strDay = Request("Day")
strMonth = Request("Month")
strYear = Request("Year")

InputDate =  strYear & "-" & strMonth & "-" & strDay
if IsDate(InputDate) Then
    InsertDate = CDate(InputDate)
else
'if date typed wrong, use Todays Date
    InsertDate = Date()
end if

SQLUPD = "UPDATE MyDataBase SET DateField = '"& FormatDateTime(InsertDate, vbShortDate) &"'"
SQLINS = "INSERT INTO MyDataBase (DateField, Alist, Atype, Acomment) VALUES ('"& FormatDateTime(InsertDate, vbShortDate) &"', .....
```

Then all sorting and output opration with dates are going well.