# MS Access DateDiff Ambiguous Dates (Day Month order) Returning bad results

Tags: ms-access, datediff

```
tblDurations
  TaskID : Number
  Assigned Date : Date/Time
  Start Date : Date/Time
  End Date : Date/Time

SELECT TaskID,
  Count(TaskID) As [Task Count],
  Min(Nz([Start Date], [Assigned Date])) as [Min of Start Date],
  Max([End Date]) as [Max of End Date],
  DateDiff("d", Min(Nz([Start Date], [Assigned Date])), Max([End Date])) + 1 as [Date Range]
  FROM tblDurations
  GROUP BY TaskID
```

Output:

```
TaskID  Task Count Min of Start Date Max of End Date Date Range
1       3          16/08/2018        10/01/2019      1
2       2           4/09/2017        07/09/2017      4
3       3          13/09/2017        08/01/2018      118
```

I am getting the occasional row as shown in row 1 (TaskID = 1) which should equal 148!

After a lot of checking I determined this occurs for dates that are ambiguous.  By that I mean where the day and months values can be confused for each other.

I'm in Australia where the date formnat is dd/mm/yyyy.  However I believe the datediff function is confusing the day and month order and returning Zero (plus my 1 = 1).

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: If it would be due to dates between what you call ambiguous you would have an issue with TaskID 2 too, Please enclose all data for all Task ID's.

Comment: Maybe your fellow Aussie Allen Browne can help http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html

Comment: @Rene You were on right track.  I had over simplified my example.  Which I have now expanded in the original post.  See my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date Format changes when inserting into table if start date and end date cross one or more months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714445/date-format-changes-when-inserting-into-table-if-start-date-and-end-date-cross-o)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not the ambiguous dates.  Looking closer I found various non ambiguous dates returning bad values.

The problem was the use of an Nz function which I was using like this :

Min(NZ([Start Date], [Assigned Date]))

Which I took to mean take the Min of either the Start Date, but if the start date does is NULL then the min of the Assigned Date.

What does work is this :

Nz(Min([StartDate], Min(Assigned Date))

All fixed.

Which begs the question. Why only sometimes? As it was not related to Start Dates being NULL or not NULL.

Thanks everyone for feed back!

Comment: Did the links in other comments provide insight?